# Readonly at child control not longer "readonly" when parent control hide and re-display it

Tags: orbeon

I have 2 levels of radio controls as below. The issue is after initial loading, child control is working correctly, whereby I would not be able to perform selection on it; But once I go to parent control, choose an option to hide the child control, and then re-select another option to show the child control, even though child control color is dim off, but i'm able to select the child control's option. In other words, the cursor on child control does not change to "cross" image.

IMPORTANT: this issue only happen on latest version 2016.2.1, previous version 2016.2 is working fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might match [issue #2890](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2890), which got recently fixed. However I think that issue was already present in 2016.2 and 2016.2.1.

Can you provide a simple example with steps so I can try to reproduce it and make sure that is in fact the same as #2890?

Comment: Hi ebruchez, i'm attending workshop this week, will give you example next week, thanks again.